# C++ Function Problem

Tags: c++, function

I have gone over this back and forth and keep getting this error: 'ReadDials' : function does not take 0 arguments, can I get at least a point in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//declaring function
int ReadDials(int);

int main()
{
    //declaring each character of the phone number
    char num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8;
    bool quit = false;
    int code;

    while(quit != true || quit != true)
    ReadDials(code);
    if (code == -5)
        cout << "I love football!" << endl;
    else 
        return 0;
}

int ReadDials()
{
    //getting number from user
    cout << "Enter a phone number (Q to quit): ";
    cin >> num1;
    if (num1 == 'q' || num1 == 'Q')
    {
        code = -5;
        return code;
    }
    cin >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5 >> num6 >> num7 >> num8;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Why don't you call ReadDials(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, code) in your main function?

Comment: No I am trying to learn functions better so I wanted to try to write a program that uses them.

Comment: You may want to consider learning about [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

Comment: Now I am getting undeclared variable names but they are declared in main and I dont need them to come out of the function just determine what the value for "code" will be.

Comment: It is not nice to edit the code without changing the question. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually ReadDials takes 9 arguments, so you can't call ReadDials() without passing anithing to it. then, as far as I can see, the function "karma" seems to return the number the user "dials", but it will *probably fail* in this intent, since parameters are passed by value, so the function changes are not propagate outside. To achieve this you will probably better passa to the function a char*, or why not reading the whole number as a string ?

Comment: I want to set it up where it doesnt need anything brought in, it just needs to spit out the int code.

Comment: so you probably neeed to redesign the function.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `ReadDials` to be a function with 9 arguments:

```
int ReadDials(char, char, char, char, char, char, char, char, int);
```

and then you call it providing none:

```
while(quit != true || quit != true)
ReadDials();
```

The compiler complains. Is that surprising?

Answer (score 0):

`readDials` is declared as a function taking several parameters, so calling it without providing the corresponding arguments is an error.

Answer (score 0):

you must provide the arguments:

```
const int result(ReadDials(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, code));
```